# Eclipse project build-path -- conflicting error

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse is giving an error to build-path of the Gradle project on it --

> Cannot nest '/src/test/resources' inside /src/test'. To enable the nesting exclude 'resources/' from '/src/test'

So I do what it asks – both of these two --

1. by the solution here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-declare-an-exclusion-on-my-source-folder/22821 added
   `exclude 'src/test/resources'` 
   into the Java srcDirs in the `sourceSets> .. >java` block already there is in the `build.gradle` file of the project,
2. and via Eclipse—made it exclude the `/test/resources'` from the build-path, just as it asks.

But I sill see the error on the build-path.

[Cleared the project name-s in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29sWn.png)

EDIT: image shows way after applying the changes i made-- a latter open of the source/edit window. i'm a Java  eng of many yrs. just new on Gradle.

Is this a mismatch on the Eclipse/Buildship plugin and the Gradle version? Not savvy on Gradle/yet, but looks like Gradle isn’t backward compatible.
Versions are:

- Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0
- Eclipse 2020-06
- Gradle 5.5
- Java 11

I imported as a Gradle project.

TIA

Comment: You have obscured paths in your images that might have been useful information. **No one cares** what your workspace projects are named. You also have not shown the entire list of entries in the Build Path property page Source tab.

Comment: @nitind my confidentiality agreement does care abt all things to code. i'll see to the rest.

Comment: Your problem is that you have the source folder `src/test/` and also the source folder `src/test/resources` nested/inside of the first source folder. Nesting source folders does not make sense, does it? Instead, you should have `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` for your test code and for your test resources.

Comment: @howlger - relative-from-above then. write this as an ans and i'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the source folder **`src/test/`** and another source folder **`src/test/resources` inside/nested** in the first source folder. Nesting source folders does not make sense and is therefore not allowed. Hence the error message.

Instead, you should have the source folders `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` for your test code and for your test resources.